# I have a vue template using vuetify and I want to install nuxt js in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I hope you are doing well

I would like to aks you about how can I install Nuxt js in the Vue template to benefit the features of Nuxt js

for example file structure and easy routing ..etc

is there any help?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest thing you could do is to use

```
npx create-nuxt-app my-app
```

An option is prompted to include UI framework of your choice, Vuetify is there.